# C differentiate between a function and a struct

Tags: c

In my OS (vxWorks) there is a struct called `stat`, and a function called `stat`.

If I `memset((void*)&myStruct, 0, sizeof(stat));`

Am I using size of the function, or the struct? The IDE bolds **stat** as if it's a function. How can I imply to use the struct?

Comment: `sizeof(struct stat)`?

Comment: `sizeof( mystruct )`.  And in C, you don't need to cast addresses to `void *`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `struct` tags live in *different* namespace - they don't name types. There is also indeed a function named [`stat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stat.html).

You must use

```
sizeof (struct stat)
```

to get the size of the [`struct` with the tag `stat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html).

If you use `sizeof (stat)` (i.e. `sizeof stat`), the `stat` *function* will be converted to pointer-to-function, and that's what `sizeof` evaluates, resulting in e.g. 4 or 8, depending on the width of the pointer.

---

*If* there was a *typedef*, then that could be used instead of `struct stat` without the `struct` keyword:

```
typedef struct stat STAT;

...

sizeof (STAT)
```

---

Even better: remove the cast to `(void*)` - it is needless in C. And use `sizeof` with the *variable instead*:

```
memset(&myStruct, 0, sizeof myStruct);
```

Notice that `sizeof` needs parentheses only for types and not for expressions.

Comment: That's new to me: `sizeof myStruct` will return `sizeof(struct stat)` ?

Comment: @ICU_ it will return the `sizeof myStruct`. if `myStruct` is *not* of type `struct stat` then it is meaningless to zero first `sizeof (struct stat)` bytes of it...

Comment: Why do all the programmers around me insist on using the `sizeof` the struct definition then? Is there some case where this is required? Ie using the size of the type vs the variable?

Comment: @ICU_ well, they *don't*. It depends.

Comment: Also, `sizeof` always works with the *size of the type* - but it can be a) a named type or b) the type of an expression.